# Online Presence in SharePoint 2010

Tags: icons, sharepoint-2010

Has anyone tried with online presence in SharePoint 2010? I used to take help of imnrc javascript function in MOSS 2007 but the same does not seem to work in SharePoint 2010.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMNRC() still works in SP2010. Are you using the correct capitalization of the function name? Are you getting any errors? Can you provide a code sample?